# How to do conditional validation in spring boot?

Tags: validation, spring-boot, bean-validation, spring-rest

I am developing a Spring REST application.

I have a DTO

```
private String name;
@
private String nationality;
private String matchType;
private List<NC_Field> ncFields = new ArrayList();
// Getters and Setters
```

I have 3 tables

1. Field Table
2. Name Clearance Table
3. NC_Fields Table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can have a custom validator defined with whatever logic you want. 
Then you can create a custom annotation for the validator and use it in your DTO just like `@NotNull`

```
public class CustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyObject, String> {
  .
  .
  .
}
```

--

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = { CustomValidator.class })
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ContactInfo {
    String message() default "Invalid value";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

refer to this link for example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dynamic-dto-validation

Comment: How to check if nationality is INDIAN, then PAN is mandatory. Else it is not. Likewise there are some more conditions.

Comment: when you implement `ConstraintValidator` you need to override the validate method. This is the place where you can pretty much write entire logic